# JSONObject to date in java using toBean

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am trying to convert a JSON object to a simple POJO Bean. One of the field is a date and it is taking the system date instead of the date passed in JSON.
Sample code

static List dataList = new ArrayList();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String jsonEx = "{\"data\":[{\"YEAR\":\"2016\",\"tradeDate\":\"Oct 20, 2016 12:10:00 PM\",\"tradeMonth\":\"October\"}]}";


    JSONObject jsonMain = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonEx);
    JSONArray jsonArr=jsonMain.getJSONArray("data");
    if(jsonArr.isArray()){                      
        for(Object obj : jsonArr){
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;
            dataList.add((mypojo)JSONObject.toBean(jObj, mypojo.class));
        }
    }

    for(mypojo pojo : dataList){
        System.out.println(pojo.getTradeDate() + "::" + pojo.getTradeMonth());
    }
}
```

Output:
Mon Mar 19 12:44:19 EDT 2018::October

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [MorpherRegistry](http://ezmorph.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/ezmorph/MorpherRegistry.html?is-external=true) before to serialize the json.

```
MorpherRegistry mr = JSONUtils.getMorpherRegistry();
mr.registerMorpher(new DateMorpher(new String[] {YOUR_FORMAT}));
```

So your code should be like:

```
static List dataList = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonEx = "{\"data\":[{\"YEAR\":\"2016\",\"tradeDate\":\"Oct 20, 2016 12:10:00 PM\",\"tradeMonth\":\"October\"}]}";

    MorpherRegistry mr = JSONUtils.getMorpherRegistry();
    mr.registerMorpher(new DateMorpher(new String[] {YOUR_FORMAT}));

    JSONObject jsonMain = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonEx);
    JSONArray jsonArr=jsonMain.getJSONArray("data");
    if(jsonArr.isArray()){                      
        for(Object obj : jsonArr){
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;
            dataList.add((mypojo)JSONObject.toBean(jObj, mypojo.class));
        }
    }

    for(mypojo pojo : dataList){
        System.out.println(pojo.getTradeDate() + "::" + pojo.getTradeMonth());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My pojo uses date class for the tradeDate field so it is class casting exception with this now.

Comment: In which line do you get the exception?